# Checkbox not working in header of uib-accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

If i place checkbox in header of uib-accordion, its not getting checked

```
<uib-accordion>
  <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default"
    is-open="daily"
    is-disabled="false">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="daily">
          Daily
        </label>
      </div>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    This content is straight in the template.
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: jsfiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/p0optzn7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accordion is capturing the checkbox click event, you will need to stop propagating the event to the accordion when you click the checkbox

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="preventCheck($event)" ng-model="daily">
```

JS

```
$scope.preventCheck = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

You can even inline it if you want

```
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"
```

Comment: this works Thanks. But How this makes the checkbox model checked and uncheked??

Comment: whether the input is checked or unchecked is determined by HTML, `ng-model` listens to attribute changes in your input and updated `daily` accordingly. so in my example, ng-click only prevents the click event from affecting the accordion

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="somevalue" ng-model="daily">
```

You can put alos ng-true-value and ng-false-value

Answer (score 0):

Try uib-btn-checkbox directive. This will toggle your binded model on click.

Use ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" to stop click events from bubbling up

```
<input type="checkbox" uib-btn-checkbox ng-model="daily" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
```